# How to define an instance of Data.Foldable.Constrained?

Tags: haskell, category-abstractions

I've successfully defined Category, Functor, Semigroup, Monoid constrained. Now I'm stuck with Data.Foldable.Constrained. More precisely, I seem to have correctly defined the unconstrained functions fldl and fldMp, but I can't get them to be accepted as Foldable.Constrained instances.
My definition attempt is inserted as a comment.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists, GADTs, TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds, 
FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, StandaloneDeriving, TypeApplications #-}

import Prelude ()

import Control.Category.Constrained.Prelude
import qualified Control.Category.Hask as Hask
-- import Data.Constraint.Trivial
import Data.Foldable.Constrained
import Data.Map as M
import Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Foldable as FL

main :: IO ()
main = print $ fmap (constrained @Ord (+1))
             $ RMS ([(1,[11,21]),(2,[31,41])])

data RelationMS a b where
  IdRMS :: RelationMS a a
  RMS :: Map a (Set b) -> RelationMS a b 
deriving instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (RelationMS a b)

instance Category RelationMS where
    type Object RelationMS o = Ord o
    id = IdRMS
    RMS mp2 . RMS mp1
      | M.null mp2 || M.null mp1 = RMS M.empty
      | otherwise = RMS $ M.foldrWithKey 
            (\k s acc -> M.insert k (S.foldr (\x acc2 -> case M.lookup x mp2 of
                                                        Nothing -> acc2
                                                        Just s2 -> S.union s2 acc2
                                             ) S.empty s
                                    ) acc
            ) M.empty mp1

(°) :: (Object k a, Object k b, Object k c, Category k) => k a b -> k b c -> k a c
r1 ° r2 = r2 . r1

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Semigroup (RelationMS a b) where
    RMS r1 <> RMS r2 = RMS $ M.foldrWithKey (\k s acc -> M.insertWith S.union k s acc) r1  r2 

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Monoid (RelationMS a b) where
    mempty = RMS M.empty
    mappend = (<>)

instance Functor (RelationMS a) (ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord) Hask where
    fmap (ConstrainedMorphism f) = ConstrainedMorphism $
            \(RMS r) -> RMS $ M.map (S.map f) r


fldl :: (a -> Set b -> a) -> a -> RelationMS k b -> a
fldl f acc (RMS r) = M.foldl f acc r

fldMp :: Monoid b1 => (Set b2 -> b1) -> RelationMS k b2 -> b1
fldMp m (RMS r) = M.foldr (mappend . m) mempty r


-- instance Foldable (RelationMS a) (ConstrainedCategory (->) Ord) Hask where
    -- foldMap f (RMS r)
        -- | M.null r = mempty
        -- | otherwise = FL.foldMap f r
    -- ffoldl f = uncurry $ M.foldl (curry f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `FL.foldMap (FL.foldMap f) r` in your definition so that you fold over the `Map` *and* the `Set`.

However, there's a critical error in your `Functor` instance; your `fmap` is partial. It's not defined on `IdRMS`.

I suggest using `-Wall` to have the compiler warn you about such issues.

The problem comes down to you need to be able to represent relations with finite and infinite domains.  `IdRMS :: RelationRMS a a` can already be used to represent *some* relations of infinite domain, it isn't powerful enough to represent a relation like `fmap (\x -> [x]) IdRMS`.

One approach is to use `Map a (Set b)` for finite relations and `a -> Set b` for infinite relations.

```hs
data Relation a b where
   Fin :: Map a (Set b) -> Relation a b
   Inf :: (a -> Set b) -> Relation a b

image :: Relation a b -> a -> Set b
image (Fin f) a = M.findWithDefault (S.empty) a f
image (Inf f) a = f a
```

This changes the category instance accordingly:

```hs
instance Category Relation where
  type Object Relation a = Ord a

  id = Inf S.singleton

  f . Fin g = Fin $ M.mapMaybe (nonEmptySet . concatMapSet (image f)) g
  f . Inf g = Inf $ concatMapSet (image f) . g

nonEmptySet :: Set a -> Maybe (Set a)
nonEmptySet | S.null s = Nothing
            | otherwise = Just s

concatMapSet :: Ord b => (a -> Set b) -> Set a -> Set b
concatMapSet f = S.unions . fmap f . S.toList
```

And now you can define a total `Functor` instance:

```hs
instance Functor (Relation a) (Ord ⊢ (->)) Hask where
  fmap (ConstrainedMorphism f) = ConstrainedMorphism $ \case -- using {-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
    Fin g -> Fin $ fmap (S.map f) g
    Inf g -> Inf $ fmap (S.map f) g
```

But a new issue raises its head when defining the `Foldable` instance:

```hs
instance Foldable (Relation a) (Ord ⊢ (->)) Hask where
  foldMap (ConstrainedMorphism f) = ConstrainedMorphism $ \case
    Fin g -> Prelude.foldMap (Prelude.foldMap f) g
    Inf g -> -- uh oh...problem!
```

We have `f :: b -> m` and `g :: a -> Set b`. `Monoid m` gives us `append :: m -> m -> m`, and we know `Ord a`, but in order to generate all the `b` values in the image of the relation, we need all the possible `a` values!

One way you could try to salvage this is to use `Bounded` and `Enum` as additional constraints on the relation's domain. Then you could try to enumerate all the possible `a` values with `[minBound..maxBound]` (this may not be list every value for all types; I'm not sure if that's a law for `Bounded` and `Enum`).

```hs
instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Foldable (Relation a) (Ord ⊢ (->)) Hask where
  foldMap (ConstrainedMorphism f) = ConstrainedMorphism $ \case
    Fin g -> Prelude.foldMap (Prelude.foldMap f) g
    Inf g -> Prelude.foldMap (Prelude.foldMap f . g) [minBound .. maxBound]
```

Comment: I found your answer very informative. However, being a very different approach to the problem than I had set up, I need time to "digest" it. The Enum and Bounded limitations leave me very perplexed (even if they are a logical consequence of your approach); so I wonder if there are no other less restrictive approaches.

Comment: I integrated the code following the error messages of Wall.
I was therefore inspired by the fact that in the definition of Fractional Double "not all elements of Double have an multiplicative inverse". Considering that the identity for Relation only has a formal function, I hypothesized that the problems related to IdRMS could be solved using "undefined" when necessary, and therefore I completed the code in this sense. Since for "the Wall" no longer produces error messages, could an instance of Foldable.Constrained be formulated which is simpler and less restrictive than the one you proposed?

Comment: `Double` has the excuse of needing to be compatible with [IEEE floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Using `undefined` or `error` to satisfy a typeclass is generally frowned on. `fmap` producing an exception would be EXTREMELY surprising. If my solution is too complex, then simplify by looking at what you need from your relation. If you don't need the category interface, then you can drop `Identity`/`Inf` and just use the `Map a (Set b)` representation. If you don't need to enumerate inputs (e.g. for `Foldable`), drop the `Map a (Set b)` representation and just use `a -> Set b`.

Comment: On `Enum` and `Bounded`: this looks like a good fit for [`Finite` from *universe*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.1/docs/Data-Universe.html#t:Finite) (cc @AlbertoCapitani ).

Comment: @duplode A bit off topic: is it right to think of Data.Universe a version of Gödel's numbering system?

Comment: It’s more like proofs that the rationals or Z^2 has the same cardinality as N

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani `Universe` instances are recursively enumerable. (A Gödel numbering would be one possible of achieving that.)

Comment: Thank you all for letting me discover and start connecting very interesting topics. I will have a lot to study. I will still take advantage of this "out of topic" to ask you if Data.Singletons is in some way similar to Data.Universe and, if so, if they are two libraries created for two different Haskells (Data.Singletons, if I I have not misunderstood, it serves to prepare the transition of Haskel to Dependent Types).